# Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous in YII

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am new in YII. Trying to implement the query in controller, Below is my code which has taken from controller.

```
public function getCommentListByUser($user_id)
{
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->select = "username";
        $criteria->alias = "u";
            $criteria->condition = 'cmt.commented_userd_id  = '.$user_id;
            $criteria->join = 'JOIN tbl_taskcomment cmt ON  (cmt.commented_userd_id = u.id)';
            $criteria->order = 'cmt.id ASC';  
            $model = User::model()->findAll($criteria);  
            return $model;
}
```

when i ran the page, I got the following error,

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT id, username, email, createtime, lastvisit, superuser, status FROM `tbl_users` `u` JOIN tbl_taskcomment cmt ON (cmt.commented_userd_id = u.id) WHERE cmt.commented_userd_id = 1 ORDER BY cmt.id ASC

Instead fetching username from USER table,it comes with all column with out alias name. I knew this issue related with alias name. What i done wrong on this syntax as well as code.

Kindly advice

Comment: You shouldn't write sql for this, use your models' relations and ActiveRecord's find method. If you used Gii to generate your models, you should already have relations set up. Post them, and I can help.

Answer (score 4):

**Either**

change:  `$criteria->select = "username" to ==>  $criteria->select = "u.username"`

**OR**

remove:  `$criteria->alias = "u" and change $criteria->select = "username" to ==> $criteria->select = "t.username" and change all left join alias 'u.field_name' to ==> 't.field_name'`

Answer (score 2):

This should help you:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#disambiguating-column-names

Answer (score 0):

You maybe have id column in both the tables.
If you need columns from table `tbl_users` you should use alias to get each column:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.email, u.createtime, u.lastvisit, u.superuser, u.status FROM tbl_users u
```

And your WHERE condition should be:

```
WHERE u.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I faced some problems with aliases in `CDbCriteria`.
Can you try default alias (which is `t`)?

Comment: I mean remove `$criteria->alias = "u"` and replace `u` with `t` in your code sample. Try to specify alias in `select` property: `$criteria->select = "t.username";`