# Yii: How to refer to model's field when columns name duplication performing relational query?

Tags: php, yii

I try to execute this relational query in Yii:

```
$r = MachineData::model()->with('machineGames')->findByPk($machine_id);
```

but it returns this error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42702]: Ambiguous column: 7         ERROR: column reference "machine_id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ..."."game_id") WHERE ("t"."machine_id"=3) ORDER BY machine_id...
```

It seems the problem is in `ORDER BY` clause where the reference to `machine_id` is unclear. It may refer to both of the tables because they both have `machine_id` column. Can you suggest me any solution, please?
REGARDS!

P.s.
Using the following CDbCriteria gives the same error:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->alias = "u";
$criteria->compare('u.machine_id',$machine_id);
$criteria->with = array('machineGames');
$r = MachineData::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

This is the relation in model `MachineData`:

```
abstract class BaseMachineData extends GxActiveRecord {
  public function relations() {
    return array('machineGames' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'MachineGames', 'machine_id', 'order'=>'machine_id', 'with'=>'game');
    }
  //code goes here
}

class MachineData extends BaseMachineData{
   //code goes here
}
```

This is the relation in model MachineGames:

```
abstract class BaseMachineGames extends GxActiveRecord {
  public function relations() {
    return array('machine' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'MachineData', 'machine_id');
  }
  //code goes here
}

class MachineGames extends BaseMachineGames
{
  //code goes here
}
```

Comment: Please add your `CDbCriteria` definition. In general you can set an alias for one table in such a case, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310593/column-id-in-field-list-is-ambiguous-in-yii

Comment: It neither works with criteria.

Comment: Could you show use the relations you declared in both of your models?

Comment: Yeap I think the problem comes from the relations, Herode answer seems fine to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies in your *MachineData::relations()* method:

```
public function relations() {
    return array('machineGames' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'MachineGames', 'machine_id', 'order'=>'machine_id', 'with'=>'game');
    }
```

You should disambiguate *machine_id* here as explained in the docs for [CActiveRecord::relations()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail) :

```
public function relations() {
    return array('machineGames' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'MachineGames', 'machine_id', 'order'=>'machineGames.machine_id', 'with'=>'game');
    }
```

**NB** : The code above is using the relation's name, hence the *machine_games.machine_id* column. If you want to disambiguate on the main table column (here : *machine_data.machine_id*), use the alias 't'.

Comment: I got rid of `order` rule and the error message doesn't show. It's alright this way and I'll leave it like that. Just to note that it seems the problem is like what @Herode described but in his suggesting Yii still complains that `machineGames` in `machineGames.machine_id` doesn't exist. But I don't care as long as I excluded `order` clause from the code. Thank you @Herode. I love you :)

Comment: @0xC0DEGURU  You're welcome. Anyway, as soon as I'll have a few minutes for this, I'll try to find out what's wrong in the suggested code and update it. It's better to publish non buggy solutions ;o)